# JSON decoding array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this JSON code:

```
{
    "phrases": [
        {
            "phrases": [
                {
                    "id": "33",
                    "text": "sasdsad",
                    "date": "2012-03-14 20:28:45",
                    "views": "0",
                    "ip": "64.191.90.5",
                    "reported": "0",
                    "strange": "0",
                    "lang": "en"
                },
                {
                    "id": "32",
                    "text": "que ondaa\r\n",
                    "date": "2012-03-14 20:27:45",
                    "views": "0",
                    "ip": "64.191.90.5",
                    "reported": "0",
                    "strange": "0",
                    "lang": "en"
                },
                {
                    "id": "31",
                    "text": "dsadssadsad",
                    "date": "2012-03-14 20:27:35",
                    "views": "0",
                    "ip": "64.191.90.5",
                    "reported": "0",
                    "strange": "0",
                    "lang": "en"
                }
            ],
            "details": {
                "success": "true",
                "phrase_id": "",
                "phrase_text": "",
                "phrase_date": ""
            }
        }
```

I don't really know what to do. I get some phrases vía MySQL, and pushes them to an array. This array is `json_encoded()` and gets printed.

```
$sth = $sql;
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$sth = $sql;
$data = array(
    "success" => "true", 
    "phrase_id"      => "",
    "phrase_text"      => "",
    "phrase_date"      => "",
);
    print json_encode($rows).json_encode($data);
```

and with jQuery I was trying to parse it, but I can't. This is the main problem.

```
function getPhrases(order,limit,last){
    var req_url = ...;
    $.getJSON(req_url, function(data) {
        $.each(data.phrases, function(i, data) {
            appendPhrase(data.text);
            lastid = data.id;
        });
        $.each(data.details, function(i, data) {
            $("#phrases-count").html(data.totalcount);
        });
    });
}
```

PS: I was doing this with "echo" but got some problems.

```
{
    "phrases": [
        {
            "id": "33",
            "text": "sasdsad",
            "date": "2012-03-14 20:28:45",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "64.191.90.5",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "text": "que ondaa<br />",
            "date": "2012-03-14 20:27:45",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "64.191.90.5",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "text": "dsadssadsad",
            "date": "2012-03-14 20:27:35",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "64.191.90.5",
            "lang": "en"
        }
    ],
    "details": [
        {
            "totalcount": "3",
            "logged_in": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply combine these JSON arrays:

```
print json_encode($rows).json_encode($data);
```

Try this (attempt 2):

```
print json_encode( array('phrases' => $rows, 'details' => $data) );
```

Comment: Just in my question, see the last part.

Comment: Please add the JSON structure you want to get.

Comment: Sorry, the JSON is yet different. Also need to fetch it thru jQuery. thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8941/discussion-between-luis-and-comfreek)